# Рефлексия. Как вызвать метод с ref generic параметрами?

Tags: c#, generics, рефлексия, ref

Имеем такой класс и метод

```
public class TestClass
{
    public void Swap<T>(ref T first, ref T second)
    {
        T tmp = second;
        second = first;
        first = tmp;
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь задействовать рефлексию и вызвать метод

```
[TestMethod]
public void InvokeGenericMethod()
{
    MethodInfo method = typeof(TestClass).GetMethod("Swap");
    MethodInfo methodWithInt = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));

    int one = 1;
    int two = 2;
    object[] arguments = { one, two };
    methodWithInt.Invoke(this, arguments);//здесь ошибка

    Assert.AreEqual(one, 2);
}
```

и получаю ошибку `{"Объект не соответствует конечному типу."}`

Как это делается? Гуглеж приводил к примерам с одним параметром `out` и чего-то все вызывалось как обычно, т.е. массив аргументов создавался как у меня, а далее обычный вызов через `Invoke()`. Какие идеи?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы вызываете нестатический метод, и должны передать в качестве первого аргумента `Invoke` объект, у которого вы этот метод хотите вызвать. И это должен быть объект того класса, метод которого вы вызываете:

```
methodWithInt.Invoke(new TestClass(), arguments);
```

Или вы можете поменять метод на статический, и передавать `null` в качестве первого аргумента:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static void Swap<T>(ref T first, ref T second)
    {
        T tmp = second;
        second = first;
        first = tmp;
    }
}
```

```
methodWithInt.Invoke(null, arguments);
```

Кстати, в [MSDN по `Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) подробно расписано, в каких случаях он бросает `TargetException`. Стандартная документация значительно облегчает поиск причины ошибки :)

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я не учел, точнее забыл про этот момент вызова. Но, с другой стороны я обнаружил, что тест не проходит, т.е. `one != 2`. Или результат теперь надо дергать из массива аргументов?

Comment: @Bulson а на one и two вы ссылки не сохраняете в arguments, а просто копируете их значения. https://ideone.com/xWk6kP

Comment: @4per, я уже разобрался, спасибо.